# Use the Outlook/Office365 REST API to send mail from connected email address

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am trying to send an email using the Outlook/Office 365 REST API, and I am trying to send it as an address that I have as a "Connected Account". Attempting to send the message returns a `` error. However, the API *will* let me create a draft with this address.

Additionally, I can send the API-created draft just fine, and I can also create and send messages as this account from the web interface.

Is there a way to authorize the API to be able to send a message as an address for a connected account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API doesn't support this today. It has to do with the scope of the permissions that you consent to. "Allow this app to send mail as you" covers sending from your account, but not from another account, even if you have been granted access.

Comment: Is this something on the roadmap, or is this something that is unlikely to be supported?

Comment: It is something being considered, but it's not a definite thing.

Comment: If you need a story to justify the feature, here is our use case. Our app sends emails. People may sign up with us using a different account than the one they intend to use to send emails (e.g. sign up with a personal account, but want to send emails from out app using their corporate account). This restricts us to only allowing people who want to send using Outlook/O365 to sign up with the address they want to send from. GMail *does* let us send from connected accounts, as long as the account we want to send as has been set up properly. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @JasonJohnston can you update based on the API today? There is permissions now for delegated "Send mail on behalf of others".  However my code for this always fails with a 400 Bad Request error.  The same exact code works when I send it from my mailbox.  Also, I can send email as this user from Outlook.  I can't find any code samples currently either for sending on behalf of others so not sure if this is all plumbed in or ??

Comment: Yes, the permission scopes are there and the API should support it. I'll try to whip up a quick sample and update my answer.

Comment: On re-reading the OP's question, he's asking about connected accounts, which aren't the same as delegates. A connected account is for example if you add your personal GMail account (it's in OWA settings). The API doesn't support connected accounts. Delegates (where the delegate is in your Office 365 org) should work though.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up: the way I got this to work is that you POST the message to `/me/sendmail`,but you set the `From` property on the message to the user who's granted the authenticated user "Send As" or "Send on Behalf" rights.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can think about is to leverage App-only authentication. You can configure a Azure AD App to have App-only authentication. After that, all the request will behalf of that app id and you should be able to delegate that app id to send email to anyone on behalf of the user you want. 
The following is the steps:

- Create a Azure AD application.
- Configure your Azure AD Application to allow App-only token by
  following [Build service and daemon apps in Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365). You also
  need a certificate for app-only token request.
- Go to your Azure AD Application->Configuration, Click "Add
  application" to add "Office 365 Exchange Online". Select "Send email
  as any user" under "Application permission" dropdown box. It allows
  your Azure AD App to have permission to send email on behalf of
  someone.
- Once you have Azure AD application configured, you can refer the
  following code for sending email on behalf of a specific user.

  ```
  string tenantId = "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com";
  string clientId = "your client id";
  string resourceId = "https://outlook.office.com/";
  string resourceUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/service@contoso.com/sendmail"; //this is your on behalf user's UPN
  string authority = String.Format("https://login.windows.net/{1}", AUTHORITYURL, tenantId);
  string certificatPath = @"c:\test.pfx"; //this is your certficate location.
  string certificatePassword = "xxxx"; // this is your certificate password
  var itemPayload = new
  {
      Message = new
      {
          Subject = "Test email",
          Body = new { ContentType = "Text", Content = "this is test email." },
          ToRecipients = new[] { new { EmailAddress = new { Address = "test@cotoso.com" } } }
      }
  };

  //if you need to load from certficate store, use different constructors. 
  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certficatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
  AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

  ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

  //get the access token to Outlook using the ClientAssertionCertificate
  var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, cac);
  string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

  //initialize HttpClient for REST call
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json"); 

  //setup the client post
  HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemPayload));
  //Specify the content type. 
  content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
  HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
  if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      //email send successfully.
  }else
  {
      //email send failed. check the result for detail information from REST api.
  }
  ```

For a complete explanation, please reference to my blog [Send email on behalf of a service account using Office Graph API](https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/send-email-on-behalf-of-a-service-account-using-office-graph-api-6b013728a155#.hseb07x2l)

I hope it helps and let me know if you have questions.